# diagonalisation as well as nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, nilpotence

[image]

Confused with this one. Matrix A is not diagonalisable so how can we do this ?

$$LN+N^2=AN$$
$$N(L+N)=AN$$
$$NA=AN$$
similarly, $$LA=AL$$
what to do now ?

Comment: Pure guess but I think  it works: For $L$ just replace the top right hand block by a block of zeroes.

Comment: I dont think so, I tried it using software

Comment: Do you know about Jordan normal form? If you put your matrix in JNF, and for each block you break it into the diagonal part and the non-diagonal part, that gives you the decomposition. However, there are other approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Assumption: we are working over the complex numbers.

Let your $A=\begin{bmatrix} X & J\\O & Y\end{bmatrix}$.

Now set $L=\begin{bmatrix} X & O\\O & Y\end{bmatrix}$ and $N=\begin{bmatrix} O & J\\O & O\end{bmatrix}$ so that $A=L+N$.

Now $N^2=O$, and as each of $X$ and $Y$ has characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2+2$ with distinct roots, each is diagonalisable and so therefore is $L$.

It remains to check that $LN=NL$, that is to say that $XJ=JY$. This is a simple calculation.